# como validar checkbox seleccionado en asp .net mvc5 para login?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hola lo que necesito es que con la forma de registro de usuarios que nos brinda el .net mvc5 el usuario pueda registrarse exitosamente unicamente si, solo si selecciona un textbox para aceptar terminos y condiciones ( como comunmente se ve en formularios de registro) la verdad no se como hacerlo, de antemano gracias, no adjunto codigo, puesto que no he modificado nada de lo que proporciona el visual studio en si, gracias.

pdta: no necesito que se almacene esta accion en la bd

Answer (score -1):

Es con la propiedad checked, que debería devolver true. Pero creo que este [post](http://smarrerof.blogspot.com.ar/2012/05/aspnet-mvc4-validando-que-un-campo-sea.html) te puede ayudar en lo que intentas realizar.

Saludos.